# How do I tokenize a list of texts in R

Tags: r, list, tokenize, quanteda

I have a list of texts imported from 10 documents, such as:

```
library(quanteda)
library(readtext)
path <- "the working direction"
doc1 <- readtext(paste0(path, "/*_XXX.docx"))
```

view(doc1) looks like
[[1]]  character(1)   'some words'
[[2]]  character(2)   'some words'
...

Now, I need to tokenize this list of texts, so I used

```
tok_cov1 <- doc1 %>% 
  tokens(remove_punct = TRUE,
         remove_numbers = TRUE,
         remove_symbols = TRUE) %>% 
  tokens_tolower(keep_acronyms = TRUE) %>% 
  tokens_wordstem() %>% 
  tokens_remove(pattern = stopwords("en"))
```

The code did not return with any error, but would not tokenize anything. The doc1 still looks the same as untokenized.

I am aware that specifying 'doc1' as 'doc1[[n]]' would return with tokens from the corresponding texts, e,g.,

```
tok_cov1 <- doc1[[1]] %>% 
  tokens(remove_punct = TRUE,
         remove_numbers = TRUE,
         remove_symbols = TRUE) %>% 
  tokens_tolower(keep_acronyms = TRUE) %>% 
  tokens_wordstem() %>% 
  tokens_remove(pattern = stopwords("en"))
```

However, I'd need it works on every text instead of doing the text one by one.
Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: consider unlsting your data`doc1 %>%unlist() %>%...`

Comment: Check if you are using `readtext()` correctly. It returns a data.frame, not a list.

Answer (score 0):

The **quanteda** `corpus()` function works directly on objects created by `readtext()`. So in your example, simply use:

```r
library(quanteda)
corpus(doc1) %>%
  tokens()
```

adding your preferred options for the tokenisation of course.